# Problem launching an app in release mode Flutter on an iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I can no longer launch my application in release mode on the simulator. When I type "**flutter run --release**"
I get an error message "***Release mode is not supported by iPhone 11.***". Anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Can you run "flutter doctor" command and paste output?

Comment: @Jeremy what did you see...

Comment: @chihau @Ruben I'm having the same issue. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/mgalgs/2045dd3679d5b3288f36c5cae200fc21) my `flutter doctor -v`. Looks fine (I'm not doing Android development on this device)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Release mode do not supported emulator, I solve this problem by using real device. first connect your device using usb cable, then choose the real device:

```
~/source/third-party/Cruise/ios on  master! ⌚ 12:29:28
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter run --release
Changing current working directory to: /Users/dolphin/source/third-party/Cruise
Multiple devices found:
sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile)         • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
dolphin’s iPad (mobile)             • 00008020-000E78C01EC3002E            • ios         • iOS 14.0
iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • D233A502-B00B-4FCC-B4D1-91408C88EC81 • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0 (simulator)
[0]: sdk gphone x86 arm (emulator-554)
[1]: dolphin’s iPad (00002020-000E88C01ECY002E)
[2]: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (D233A502-B00B-4FCC-B4D1-91408C88EC81)
Please choose one: [0|1|2]: 2
Release mode is not supported by iPhone SE (2nd generation).

~/source/third-party/Cruise/ios on  master! ⌚ 12:46:01
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter run --release
Changing current working directory to: /Users/dolphin/source/third-party/Cruise
Multiple devices found:
sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile)         • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
dolphin’s iPad (mobile)             • 00008020-000E78C01EC3002E            • ios         • iOS 14.0
iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • D233A502-B00B-4FCC-B4D1-91408C88EC81 • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0 (simulator)
[0]: sdk gphone x86 arm (emulator-5554)
[1]: dolphin’s iPad (00008020-000E78C01EC3002E)
[2]: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (D233A502-B00B-4FCC-B4D1-91408C88EC81)
Please choose one: [0|1|2]: 1


Launching lib/main.dart on dolphin’s iPad in release mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 6JP4P88ZJB
Running pod install...                                              2.1s
Running Xcode build...

 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        32.7s
Xcode build done.                                           193.4s
```

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem of using a **Simulator**. It's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: This is a bad answer, as it implies you should go out and buy expensive physical devices. The question was specifically related to simulators

Comment: I do not agree with your opinion, Release mode do not supported emulator，at least answer this question moment, why you going to a impossible way to solve your issue? @MikkelT

Answer (score -2):

I was having the very same error and mine was due to not having Developer mode enabled on my iPhone.

Solution as printed on the console:
**To use iPhone for development, enable Developer Mode in Settings → Privacy & Security.**