# Exception: Profile mode is not supported for iPhone 11 Pro when profile flutter app

Tags: flutter

When I run app in profile mode in Android Studio 4.1.2:

[image]

show this error:

```
Exception: Profile mode is not supported for iPhone 11 Pro.
```

why would this happen and what should I do to fix it? This is my env:

```
~/source/dabai/microservice/soa-illidan-hub on  feature/cardrobot ⌚ 22:29:08
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    ! Error: xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when xiaoqiang 的 iPhone is connected. (code -13)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

using command also failed:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open on  feature/channel ⌚ 22:42:08
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter run --profile
Profile mode is not supported by sdk gphone x86 arm.
```

Comment: you have to run the app on the real device! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147988/problem-launching-an-app-in-release-mode-flutter-on-an-ios-simulator

Answer (score 0):

If this issue occurs both on Simulator and physical device, it's possible that timeouts in the Observatory port as mentioned on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161). Try upgrading the Flutter version that you're using and see if it solves the issue. If it persists, run `flutter run --profile --verbose` to see more details on what's causing the issue.